# Implement Conversion Tracking with Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion

I'm currently trying to implement the conversion tracking feauture (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/implement_conversion_tracking/) available in Marketing Cloud and I have some questions regarding this subject.

It seems to me that it can only work with Lists and there is no mentions of how to use Data Extensions with this feature.

Do you guys have already faced this problem ? Any help would be welcome.

Thanks a lot,

Akram

Comment: Hi Akram, I face the same issue did you  get the conversion tracking working with data extension?

Comment: Hi @ManojChandran sorry for the delay. Yes indeed the solution works fine with DEs. You just have to follow the official documentation instructions http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/conversion_tracking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you will see references to List Id in the implementation steps, Conversion Tracking is agnostic of sending to lists or data extensions.

All sends have a list associated with them, whether you targeted a list or a data extension - they are used to store subscriber status. For data extension sends, they're known as 'publication lists'.

To get Conversion Tracking working, just ensure that the List Id is captured by your landing page and passed to the conversion pages along with your other parameters. Marketing Cloud will populate these parameters automatically in the initial conversion link, and process them to record your conversions.

Comment: Is it still safe to say that you cannot track 'clicks' on dynamic URLs?

Comment: @TomCallahan You should be able to track clicks on URLs containing AMPscript values, but this would probably be best as a new question.